# xaml rotate and grow label animation

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, rotation, rotatetransform

I want to make a simultaneously growing and rotating label in XAML.
Why isn't my code working? (text grows, but doesn't rotate)

```
 <Window 
  xmlns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  Title = "Animation" 
  Height = "600" Width = "1000" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

  <Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard">
            <DoubleAnimation 
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="FontSize"
            From = "12" To = "200" Duration = "0:0:4"
            RepeatBehavior = "Forever" AutoReverse="True"/>
            <DoubleAnimation
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
            From="0" To="360" Duration="0:0:4"
            RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
        </Storyboard>
  </Window.Resources>

    <Label x:Name="myLabel" Content = "Some text">
      <Label.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Label.Loaded">
          <EventTrigger.Actions>
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard}"/>
          </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
      </Label.Triggers>
    </Label>

</Window>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare a [RenderTranform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.uielement.rendertransform.aspx) (here it will be a [RotateTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.media.rotatetransform.aspx)) for your `Label` and `Storyboard.TargetName="myLabel"` are missing into your `DoubleAnimation` definitions.
If you want to know more about Transforms, you will find what you need in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750596.aspx) :

> A Transform defines how to map, or transform, points from one
>   coordinate space to another coordinate space. This mapping is
>   described by a transformation Matrix, which is a collection of three
>   rows with three columns of Double values.

The following code fixes these issues and should work (tested) :

```
 <Window 
  xmlns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  Title = "Animation" 
  Height = "600" Width = "1000" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

  <Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard">
            <DoubleAnimation 
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="FontSize" Storyboard.TargetName="myLabel"
            From = "12" To = "200" Duration = "0:0:4"
            RepeatBehavior = "Forever" AutoReverse="True"/>
                     <DoubleAnimation
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)" Storyboard.TargetName="myLabel"
            From="0" To="360" Duration="0:0:4"
            RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
        </Storyboard>
  </Window.Resources>

  <StackPanel>
    <Label x:Name="myLabel" Content = "Some text" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Label.RenderTransform>
             <RotateTransform/>
        </Label.RenderTransform>
      <Label.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Label.Loaded">
          <EventTrigger.Actions>
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard}"/>
          </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
      </Label.Triggers>
    </Label>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

If you can, i would advice you to use [Blend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296376.aspx) to create your animations, it really (really) ease the process and makes you save a lot of time! [Here is a starting point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc294948.aspx) ;)

Comment: Why the TransformGroup? Just because Blend created it? Your example would be simpler and hence better without it.

Comment: Thank you for noticing and reporting it @Clemens. Sample updated!